# Mockito - how to unit test if argument is set in a function called by another function

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I have two classes.

- Service.class
- Repository.class

My **service** is calling `cleanup()` function which then calls function from repository `repository.insertSomething(something)`

I need to test if insertSomething has set it's property after the `cleanup()` has been called.

I have started my test code like this

```
Service mock = mock(Service.class);
ArgumentCaptor<Repository> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Repository.class);
verify(mock).cleanup(); <-- have no access to the arguments of the child function and can't use the captor.
```

As given in example I have no access to the function that is called inside the scope of the cleanup function.

How do i get access to test the arguments of the function which is called by another function.

PS.

I can't call the repository function directly since it loads its argument from a configuration file. And the test should execute given that the `cleanup` function has been called.

```
// Child method
@Query("insert into .... where ?1 < ....")
void insertSomething(LocalDate date);
```

Comment: can you show the child method ? and is it in `Repository` ?

Comment: That is correct, i have edited my post

Comment: can you show the test as well ? it is confusing to me, why are you mocking service class ? and are you trying to test repository methods by calling service class method ?

Comment: There is a test I have started in the first code example, yes that is what i am trying to do, if there is a better approach i am happy to hear

Comment: You can follow the Dmitri answer below that is the recommended approach @Giedrius

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some service that you want to test. There are some inner dependencies and you want to check their calls.
For the typical service's unit test you usually should mock all of the inner dependencies and their behaviors like that:

```
class ServiceTest {

@Mock
private Repository repository;

@InjectMocks
private Service service;

@BeforeEach
void setUp(){
  initMocks(this);
}

@Test
void serviseTest(){
   SomeReturnType retVal = mock(SomeReturnType.class);

   when(repository.call(any())).thenReturn(retVal);

   service.call(any);

   verify(repository).call(any());
   verifyNoMoreInteractions(repository);
  }
}
```

This generics code can be an example of your problem's solution.